# Get all neighbors of a set of Residues

Tags: python, biopython

I have a list of residue numbers saved in  `centerResidueList = [100, 140, 170, 53]` and I am trying to get all the neighboring residues from this set of residues.
Currently I am using the script below, were I process the whole PDB file and generate a list of atom pairs with a distances of 10.0  and then iterate through the list and check if the residues number in the `all_neighbors` list correspond to a residue number in `centerResidueList`.

```
from Bio.PDB import *

centerResidueList = [100, 140, 170, 53]
neighbours_resi_number = []
structure = PDBParser().get_structure('X', "1xxx.pdb") 
atom_list = Selection.unfold_entities(structure, 'A') 
ns = NeighborSearch(atom_list)
all_neighbors = ns.search_all(10.0, "R") 
for residuepair in all_neighbors:
    resi_number = residuepair[0].id[1]
    if resi_number in centerResidueList:
        resi_number_partner = residuepair[1].id[1]
        neighbours_resi_number.append(resi_number_partner)
```

First, how can I just create the `atom_list` using CA atoms only?

Second, is `residuepair[0].id[1]` the correct way of generating the residue numbers (it works but is there a method to get this)?

Finally, are there any better solutions to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `NeighborSearch` is definitely the right idea - it constructs a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), which performs very fast lookups on nearest neighbors.

If you have just a few residues to search around, I would use the [`search()`](http://www.biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.PDB.NeighborSearch.NeighborSearch-class.html#search) method on those residues' atoms (perhaps just their CA atoms for speed). This will be more efficient than using `search_all()` then filtering. I'll answer your two questions, then provide a complete solution at the bottom.

---

> How can I just create the atom_list using CA atoms only?

You can either use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#filter), or a list comprehension (I think list comprehensions are more readable):

```
atom_list = [atom for atom in structure.get_atoms() if atom.name == 'CA']
```

---

> Second, is `residuepair[0].id[1]` the correct way of generating the residue numbers (it works but is there a method to get this)?

This is definitely the right approach. *However* (and this is a significant caveat), note that this will not handle residues with [insertion codes](http://deposit.rcsb.org/adit/docs/pdb_atom_format.html#ATOM). Why not deal with the `Residue` objects themselves?

---

My code:

```
from Bio.PDB import NeighborSearch, PDBParser, Selection


structure = PDBParser().get_structure('X', "1xxx.pdb")

chain = structure[0]['A']  # Supply chain name for "center residues"
center_residues = [chain[resi] for resi in [100, 140, 170, 53]]
center_atoms = Selection.unfold_entities(center_residues, 'A')

atom_list = [atom for atom in structure.get_atoms() if atom.name == 'CA']
ns = NeighborSearch(atom_list)

# Set comprehension (Python 2.7+, use `set()` on a generator/list for < 2.7)
nearby_residues = {res for center_atom in center_atoms
                   for res in ns.search(center_atom.coord, 10, 'R')}

# Print just the residue number (WARNING: does not account for icodes)
print sorted(res.id[1] for res in nearby_residues)
```

Comment: @DavidCain is there a way to spit out the distance value (in Angstrom) of the  NeighborSearch?